# Why do I have to use .fluxTransform(f -> f) on an inbound webflux gateways when using Java DSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I've run into failed replies when using the webflux gateway Java DSL in Spring Integration. It only works for the first few requests (<8 to be specific), I'm getting reply errors afterwards:

```java
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: 5000ms
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(JmsOutboundGateway.java:741) ~[spring-integration-jms-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

When I use `.fluxTransform(f -> f)` on the **inbound gateway** *OR* when I use the non-reactive **http outbound gateway**, I don't get the errors, even on a jmeter benchmark with thousands of requests.

- Why do I have to call `fluxTransform(f -> f)` in the **first flow** to make it work?
- Why does it work without `fluxTransform(f -> f)` when I use `Http.outboundGateway`in the **second flow**?

**Scenario**
I've created a route using four gateways for a rather complex setup to make a web request on a remote machine, but I'm

Integration Flow 1:

> inbound webflux gateway -> outbound jms gateway

```java
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow step1() {
    // request-reply pattern using the jms outbound gateway
    var gateway = Jms.outboundGateway(jmsConnectionFactory)
        .requestDestination("inboundWebfluxQueue")
        .replyDestination("outboundWebfluxQueue")
        .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID");

    // send a request to jms, wait for the reply and return message payload as response
    return IntegrationFlows.from(webfluxServer("/example/webflux"))
        // won't work consistently without the next line
        .fluxTransform(f -> f)
        .handle(gateway).get();
  }
```

Integration Flow 2:

> inbound jms gateway -> outbound webflux gateway

```java
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow step2_using_webflux() {
    var gateway = WebFlux.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/actuator/health")
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        .expectedResponseType(String.class)
        // ignore headers
        .mappedResponseHeaders();

    return IntegrationFlows.from(jmsInboundGateway())
        // use webflux outbound gateway to send the request to the TEST_URL
        .handle(gateway).get();
  }
```

The complete route looks like this:

> client web request -> flow 1 -> (message broker) -> flow 2 -> server web request

Comment: Any chances to share with us a simple Spring Boot project to reproduce an issue and play?

Comment: Sure! I've created a minimal repo here: https://github.com/duydao/webflux-integration-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use a `.channel(MessageChannels.flux())` instead of that `.fluxTransform(f -> f)`. This way we really bring a back-pressure to the the WebFlux container making it waiting for available slot in the request event loop.

With that we just send to JMS queue not-honoring back-pressure and and your JMS consumer on the other side can't keep up. Plus we send a request to the same Netty server internally acquiring an event loop slot again for those internal requests.

If you are interested I wrote a unit test like this to see what is going on:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class IntegrationApplicationTests {


    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Test
    void testSpringIntegrationWebFlux() {
        var executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(10);
        executor.afterPropertiesSet();

        var numberOfExecutions = new AtomicInteger();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                var responseEntity = this.template.getForEntity("/example/webflux", String.class);
                if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    numberOfExecutions.getAndIncrement();
                }
            });
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        assertThat(numberOfExecutions.get()).isEqualTo(100);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights.